# Which fields are available with a Facebook app access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to run some data analysis on the users of my Facebook application. I don't have their `user` access tokens stored on the server so I am planning on using my `app` access token to pull information from the graph API.

By default, calling `/{user-id}` returns

- id
- name
- first_name
- last_name
- link
- username
- location
- quotes
- favorite_teams
- gender
- email
- locale
- languages

[The documentation says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/) that the following things are available with an `app` access token:

> - Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
> - A User’s Friends and their IDs
> - Permissions granted by the User to your App

It seems that by default you get more than the basic information. Are there other things you can get with an `app` access token than the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that some other fields can be manually added by appending them to `?fields=x` in the URL.

Available fields that I've noticed so far are

- cover
- third_party_id
- installed
- permissions
- picture